# How do I bind a Command to a Checkbox in a Datatemplate in a user control?

Tags: uwp, binding, user-controls, uwp-xaml

I have a user control with a DataTemplate inside of it. In the DataTemplate is a checkbox that I want to bind a command to. I have created a dependency property to bind the command to but I cannot figure out the correct XAML syntax to bind the command from the XAML in the view to the checkbox in the user control. Then user control itself is used in a DataTemplate in the view. What I am looking for is the best way to bind a command from the viewmodel to this usercontrol. No matter how I go about it, I cannot bind the command successfully.

User Control XAML

```
<UserControl
    ...
    x:Name="orderTreeItemControl"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>        
        <DataTemplate x:Name="LocationTemplate" x:DataType="model:Location">            
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Command="{}" IsChecked="{x:Bind IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="5" MinWidth="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind LocationName}" Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopRightBottomMargin}" />
                ...
            </StackPanel>            
        </DataTemplate>
    ...
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl  x:Name="MainContent"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

User Control Code Behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Command1", typeof(ICommand), typeof(OrderTreeItemControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(Data_Changed)));
public ICommand Command1
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
}
```

View XAML

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BaseTemplate" x:DataType="model:OpenOrdersBase">
        <winui:TreeViewItem
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}"
            IsExpanded="{x:Bind IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <controls1:OrderTreeItemControl Command1="{Binding DataContext.PickToggle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}  }" Data="{Binding}">
                
            </controls1:OrderTreeItemControl>
        </winui:TreeViewItem>                                                 
    </DataTemplate>
```

### Update:

I have attempted the solution proposed by Faywang and tried binding the Command1 property in two different ways to the view. It still does not bind the command correctly.

View XAML Attempt 1:

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BaseTemplate" x:DataType="model:OpenOrdersBase">
        <winui:TreeViewItem
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}"
            IsExpanded="{x:Bind IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <controls1:OrderTreeItemControl Command1="{Binding DataContext.PickToggle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}  }" Data="{Binding}">
                
            </controls1:OrderTreeItemControl>
        </winui:TreeViewItem>                                                 
    </DataTemplate>
```

View XAML Attempt 2 (added x:name to page):

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BaseTemplate" x:DataType="model:OpenOrdersBase">
        <winui:TreeViewItem
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}"
            IsExpanded="{x:Bind IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <controls1:OrderTreeItemControl Command1="{Binding ElementName=PickSheetManager, Path=ViewModel.PickToggle}" Data="{Binding}">
                
            </controls1:OrderTreeItemControl>
        </winui:TreeViewItem>                                                 
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Binding.ElementName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.elementname) property to get the name of your user control to use as the binding source for the Binding. Then you can access its Command1 property and bind it with CheckBox. For example:

.xaml:

```
<UserControl
    ...
    x:Name="orderTreeItemControl"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="LocationTemplate" x:DataType="local:Location">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Command="{Binding ElementName=orderTreeItemControl,Path=Command1}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="5" MinWidth="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocationName}"  />
            
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
       
    </UserControl.Resources>    

    ......
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried your solution (see update) but still cannot seem to bind the command successfully.

Comment: I have solved my problem by adding the command as a property to my model. This works, but I still would like to understand how to bind the command using binding syntax.

Comment: First, what I suggested is that you can use Binding.ElementName property to bind the Command1 property to your CheckBox in the UserControl. Then for your view xaml, you need to  declare a command property in your model and then bind with Command1 property of OrderTreeItemControl. [Here](https://github.com/wcj233/BindingApp) is a simple sample I created, you can check it to see how the Binding.ElementName works.